# MKMapKit get visible annotationviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

How can I get all the visible MKAnnotationViews in

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)clickedview
```

Basically I want to make some calculation to get all the views touching (in cascade) the clickedview

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `annotationsInMapRect:` to get all the annotations inside a map rect. `visibleMapRect` will get you the current map rect to use.